# Why does my FlatList not scroll in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have seen a lot of answers for `FlatList` not scrolling for React Native, but none of the answers seem to work.

The answer usually says to add `flex: 1` to the parent, but here is an example that has that and it still doesn't scroll.

[You can test here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist), but make sure you select iOS or Android. It does scroll for web.

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",
    title: "First Item",
  },
  {
    id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",
    title: "Second Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",
    title: "Third Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d73",
    title: "Fourth Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d74",
    title: "Fifth Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d75",
    title: "Sixth Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d76",
    title: "Seventh Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d77",
    title: "Eighth Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d77",
    title: "Ninth Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d77",
    title: "Tenth Item",
  },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: works fine on Android : gif => https://file.io/hY0jcgyDxc2O

Comment: File isn't there.

Comment: @MattKuhns did the below answer your question?

Comment: You're approach worked. There also was a seat to keyboard error. On how to scroll on a emulator. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `SafeAreaView` to be within it's own container and added a `View` container with `flexGrow: 1` instead of `flex: 1`:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safe}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (<Item title={item.title} />) }
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safe: {
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```

Above worked in a snack Expo testing for iOS. Entire sample code with a little re-write:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const data = [
  {
    id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",
    title: "First Item",
  },
  {
    id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",
    title: "Second Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",
    title: "Third Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d73",
    title: "Fourth Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d74",
    title: "Fifth Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d75",
    title: "Sixth Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d76",
    title: "Seventh Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d77",
    title: "Eighth Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d77",
    title: "Ninth Item",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d77",
    title: "Tenth Item",
  },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safe}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (<Item title={item.title} />) }
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safe: {
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});

export default App
```